# Ping can not find any subdomain at all

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, dns-zone, dns-lookup

Following shows the information of my virtual environment.

computer name = sp

Full computer name = sp.spd.local

domain = spd.local

Inside DNS there is a Forward lookup zone, its name is `spd.local` and contians these:

CName: name=*, Data=sp.spd.local,

Host(A) name=sp, Data=10.0.0.4

Host(A) name=sp, Data=192.168.250.167

Ping should solve foo.spd.local, but it doesn't. Ping only finds sp.spd.local nothing else.

Appreciate all kind of advise.

Answer (score 0):

Include the domain in your wildcard:

```
*.spd.local.    IN CNAME  sp.spd.local.
```

And pay close attention to the trailing dots.  It's unclear in your original post if there was actually a dot at the end of sp.spd.local -- if there wasn't, you'd be trying to resolve sp.spd.local.spd.local.

Comment: `.local` is a special-purpose domain for Multicast DNS (see RFC6762 section 3). If you have iOS, Android, OSX or Linux devices on your network, you may be getting unexpected DNS responses that mess things up for you.